# How do you clear the bootstrap validation success (or failure) class and icon?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a form and am stuck on part of the validation. In the form I have the capability to open and close parts of the form depending on the choices that are made.  One of those choices it selecting options with radio buttons - I can select one radio button and affect additional buttons in the form.

So, if someone selects one of the radio options, the field validates like it should.  If I subsequently clear those selections via another radio button, I can change the attributes and clear the checks, but the validated check mark will not go away when those fields are cleared.

In the code below, I get the validation when I select one of the radio buttons to remove or keep a volunteer.  Clicking on the 'Clear Actions' button, clears the radio but not the validation check.

I've looked for something about this but have not been able to find anything useful in this instance.  Any help anyone could offer would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type='text/javascript' src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" s>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#theForm').bootstrapValidator({
                // framework: 'bootstrap',
                icon: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields : {
                    va: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: '* Select an action'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            });

            $("#clearRadio").click(function() {
                if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $(".volStat").prop('checked', false);
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#fff;">
<form role="form" id="theForm" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="#">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-0" for="clearRadio">Clear Actions</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-0">
        <label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left:0;"><input type="radio"  name="clearRadio" id="clearRadio" value="cl"/>Clear </label>
    </div>
    <label class="control-label col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-0"><span class="labelRequired">*</span>Action</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-0">
        <label class="radio"><input type="radio"  name="va" id="vaRemove" value="rem" class="volStat"/> Remove Volunteer</label>
        <label class="radio"><input type="radio"  name="va" id="vaRemain" value="keep" class="volStat"/> Keep Volunteer</label>
        <br><br>
        <button type = "submit" class = "btn">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
<script src="//forms.gsnetx.org/tctTest/formValidation.min.js"></script>
<script src="//forms.gsnetx.org/tctTest/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this in your `#clearRadio` click handler:

```
var data = $('#theForm').data('bootstrapValidator');
data.resetField('va');
```

Though I see that jQuery encounters an undefined object at some point in there that I have not looked in to yet. Anyway, this works and might set you in the right direction of your solution.

Working demo here: http://jsbin.com/zamiwiwihi/edit?html,output

Comment: Hey thanks - I'll take a look.  Sorry for the disappearing act - had some unexpected personal stuff come up that took all of my attention.

Comment: @43rdworld Haha, no sweat! Hope it helps you solve the issue. If not, say the word and I'll see if I can help some more :)